# Parse is replacing values as I try to update object

Tags: swift, parse-platform

[[PLEASE SEE UPDATE BELOW]]

I am trying to create a simple rating system, where a user can 'like' a video and a number is added in my Parse database. For some reason, it seems that Parse finds another object with the same rating and replaces it, so when I 'like' 10 clips, I only end up with about 3 ratings in my class somehow.

Can somebody point out what I might be doing wrong?

```
func createRating(){
    let query = PFQuery(className: "VideosInfo")
    query.whereKey("Video_ID", equalTo: videoID)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            videosTable.objectId = objects![0].objectId
            videosTable["Rating"] = 1
            videosTable.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                print("Increasing Rating")
                if (success) {
                    print("Rating Increased")
                } else {
                    print(error?.description)
                }}} else {
            print(error?.description) }}}

@IBAction func likeBtn(sender: AnyObject) {

    let query = PFQuery(className: "VideosInfo")
    query.whereKey("Video_ID", equalTo: videoID)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            if objects?.count == 0 {
                videosTable["Video_ID"] = self.videoID
                videosTable.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if (success) {
                        self.createRating()
                        print("Rating Created")
                    } else {
                        print(error?.description)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                videosTable.objectId = objects![0].objectId
                videosTable.incrementKey("Rating")
                videosTable.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    print("Increasing Rating")
                if (success) {
                    print("Rating Increased")
                    }}}} else {
                print(error?.description)
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried this in several ways. What you see in the code above was my last attempt to have Parse not overwrite my objects.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**
I noticed that the values are replaced when I click on various 'like' buttons during the same simulation. When I stop and renew, it creates a new value. So its not replacing values because of their same rating, but because I am clicking various likes on the same session. Does somebody know how to avoid this?

Comment: I'm curious how createRating() works. It's only called under the condition that the object wasn't found in videoInfo when a user likes it, yet in createRating() you perform this query all over again ? (and it shouldn't even exist)

Comment: Yes. Thats the point I try to make with createRating(). I didnt have it at first but I was trying different ways to solve my problem

Comment: my guess is you only have one videoID property because you reference it as self.videoID. If this is the case you need to use the IndexPath or otherwise identify the proper videoID based on the button that is pressed. When you press a bunch at one time, the videoID is being overwritten so when they complete they are all updating the last pressed videoID

Comment: Dave.. it sounds to me you're on the right track, but could you please clarify? 'self' is being pushed by XCode to be included, so I can't take it away. The videoID is coming from a prepareForSegue method in a table in the previous view.

Answer (score 0):

```
func createRating(){
    videosTable["Rating"] = 1;
    videosTable["Video_ID"] = videoID;
    videosTable.saveInBackgroundWithBlock(//*Do whatever*/)
}

func likeButton(){
    let query = PFQuery(className: "VideosInfo")
    query.whereKey("Video_ID",equalTo: videoID)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{(objects,error)->Void in
        if error == nil{
            if objects?.count == 0 || objects == nil{
                createRating()
            }
            else{
                objects![0].incrementKey("Rating")
                objects.saveInBackgroundWithBlock(/**Do Whatever*/)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think something like this should work. CreateRating should operating under the assumption that it doesn't exist yet, so it needs to save itself with a rating of 1 and the appropiate video id.

When you like a video, if you can't find the object, create the rating. Otherwise, just increment the object that was found and save it.

Another idea is when a video is created, you should just set the rating as 0 and then you avoid the issue of creating a rating.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.. it seems that the query is still relevant, and thus gets replaced when I try to save another video. Is there a way to "close the connection to Parse" after each rating is completed?

Comment: I'm a little confused. What do you mean by replaced ? Also, what does video id refer to ? Is it the id from another table ? or just another unique identifier. On a side note, When you run the query, it trys to fetch the relevant info from Parse backend, after it does, it calls your closure, and then it ends.

Comment: The whole object gets replaced by a mew query. The videoId is a string that I get from YouTube relating to the video that I am playing.

Comment: hm okay makes sense regarding your videoId. What's the purpose of videosTable as well? I know its a pfobject but why don't you just instantiate a PFObject within the scope of createRating? Sorry, just trying to get an understanding of what's going on outside of these two functions because I'm fairly confident these are right.

Comment: How would a instantiate a PFObject within the scope of createRating? videosTable is a class in Parse that is meant for storing a videoID and its rating based on how many likes it has.